# Vue Dynamic Components: how to select from multiple instance of the same component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vue-component, iview

I have the following problem: I am using iView as UI lib in our project, and I have to choose **Button** out of several same iView Button components inside **dynamic component**, what to pass to :is props of component. Here is an excerpt from my code:

```
  <span class="top-buttons" v-if="showTopButtons">
    <Button @click="selectAll">
      <Icon type="android-remove-circle"></Icon>
      Select All
    </Button>
    <component :is="???">
      <Button @click="moveToDrafts">
        <Icon type="android-cancel"></Icon>
        Move to Drafts
      </Button>
      <Button @click="publish">
        <Icon type="android-cancel"></Icon>
        Publish
      </Button>
      <Button @click="publish">
        <Icon type="android-cancel"></Icon>
        Publish
      </Button>
    </component>
    <Button @click="deleteTour">
      <Icon type="trash-a"></Icon>
      Delete
    </Button>
  </span>
```

Comment: show me your code about component

Answer (score 2):

`:is` prop should be passed a component

example:

```
<template>
    <component v-bind:is="currentTabComponent"></component>
</template>

<script>
import currentTabComponent from './currentTabComponent';
export default {
  components: {
    currentTabComponent,
  },
};
</script>
```

In you case, it's probably more suitable to use [`v-if`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if) instead

```
<Button @click="moveToDrafts" v-if="someCondition1">
    <Icon type="android-cancel"></Icon>
    Move to Drafts
</Button>
<Button @click="publish" v-else-if="someCondition2">
    <Icon type="android-cancel"></Icon>
    Publish
</Button>
<Button @click="publish" v-else>
    <Icon type="android-cancel"></Icon>
    Publish
</Button>
```

Comment: Yes, right. From the beginning, I knew this but wanted to check if there is a way using dynamic components :)